# Python SSLCertVerificationError with aiohttp, but OpenSSL is fine

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, exception, certificate, aiohttp

I'm trying to figure out why Python is throwing `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` exceptions for a certain endpoint I have configured, but other tools like OpenSSL / [sslscan](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) / [sslyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze) seem to be fine with it.

The context of this is that we started receiving these errors around the same time we were rotating certificates. However, I have checked the certificate ordering (Actual cert + intermediates + root, in one file, in that order from top to bottom) and that is not the problem.

The simplest example I conjured up to test this is the following:

```py
import certifi
import os
import socket
import ssl

SERVER = "myhost.example.com"
PORT = 443

context_instance = ssl.SSLContext()
context_instance.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context_instance.load_verify_locations(
    cafile=os.path.relpath(certifi.where()), capath=None, cadata=None
)
s = socket.socket()
ssl_socket = context_instance.wrap_socket(s)
ssl_socket.connect((SERVER, PORT))
print("Version of the SSL Protocol:", ssl_socket.version())
print("Cipher used:", ssl_socket.cipher())
```

For example, using `facebook.com` as the `SERVER` yields the following:

```
Version of the SSL Protocol: TLSv1.3
Cipher used: ('TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', 'TLSv1.3', 256)
```

But when I use this to test our internal endpoint, I get the following error (I also get this when I use `google.com` also, which is weird):

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    ssl_socket.connect((SERVER, PORT))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1342, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1333, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)
```

My questions are:

1. What's a foolproof way in Python 3 to verify if a TLS-enabled endpoint (let's just use HTTPS for now) is configured correctly?
2. Is there a way to achieve a more verbose error output from Python to see what the problem on my internal endpoint is? The exception does not give any more details as to what could be wrong.

For reference, this is what I'm using:

- Python 3.8.13
- OS: Debian 11
- `certifi==2022.6.15`

And this is the output from OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect myhost.example.com:443 -4 <<< "Q"

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.example.com
   i:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
 1 s:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
 2 s:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
 3 s:C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
   i:C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
---
Server certificate

<masked>

subject=CN = *.example.com

issuer=C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5687 bytes and written 409 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

Comment: What happens if you leave out the root certificate in your chain? The end point should already have the root certificate of course, otherwise it cannot trust it. Generally software should work fine even with it included, but let's assume that it doesn't (as the error indicates a self signed cert, and the root is of course self signed). Otherwise, checking what `certifi.where()` leads to would be highly recommended...

Comment: Leaving out the root certificate yields the same result. The location of `certifi.where()` is just a path on the file system that contains an up-to-date root CA bundle. For Python 3.8, it's here: `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`. I think this is  generally included so that the application does not have to rely on the CA bundle on the OS.

Comment: Right. I'm having some trouble visualizing your situation, it is not entirely clear which systems you are using and if they are client or server. Could you maybe name them explicitly? Note that "end point" could mean either client or server.

Comment: We have clients that are written in Python trying to access certain servers within our infra (given above as `myhost.example.com`), and are receiving exceptions as described above. The problem that I find is that I'm not sure why they're complaining about the server configuration when (it seems) that other clients (like OpenSSL) seem to be okay with the server's configuration.

Comment: OpenSSL is okay with the certs _it_ receives, but maybe your server (like many nowadays) uses different certs depending on SNI and you are using OpenSSL 1.1.1 or 3.0 which sends SNI automatically but python's ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket only does if you specify server_hostname which you didn't. Try `openssl s_client` with `-noservername`.

Comment: It could also be that a certificate is selected that confirms to a certain cipher suite (?). In that case TLS 1.2 should be assumed for the server. Using a proxy or sniffer (WireShark) could give you some hints.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, when I use `-noservername`, that indeed gives a certificate that is fake. We are using the NGINX Ingress controller on Kubernetes, so by default, a fake cert is generated. When I don't specify a server name, I get the default backend cert, which throws an error.

Thank you for the `server_hostname` bit, that's the part I was missing, and the reason I was getting an exception for `google.com` when I shouldn't.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 When the exception occurs, is there a way to see _which_ certificate it's failing on?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Could you convert the comment into an answer?

Comment: I will actually post the answer to the question, but I will also show the real underlying reason. It was a bug in the `aiohttp` library.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I've added the aoihttp tag to the question, even if it isn't in the question description (yet). You may want to include it into the question / title, otherwise your answer may not be useful for other devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the future, there are a couple of insightful answers here, and all of them contribute to the overall answer:

[dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085)'s answer was useful in determining that, if you want to check whether your TLS-enabled server endpoint is serving the right certificate, it's useful to run one of the following commands:

For cases where the server only serves one hostname:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect myhost.example.com:443 -4 <<< "Q"
```

For cases where the server has multiple TLS hosts that it serves, and you want to check what happens when you ***don't*** pass a server hostname:

```
$ openssl s_client -noservername -connect myhost.example.com:443 -4 <<< "Q"
```

This will show a default backend if it's an HTTP server.

For the Python bit, you need to pass in the `server_hostname`. Something like this was able to work for all valid HTTPS sites I tested:

```py
import os
import socket
import ssl

import certifi

SERVER = "myhost.example.com"
PORT = 443

context_instance = ssl.SSLContext()
context_instance.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context_instance.check_hostname = True
context_instance.load_verify_locations(
    cafile=os.path.relpath(certifi.where()), capath=None, cadata=None
)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_socket = context_instance.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=SERVER)

ssl_socket.connect((SERVER, PORT))
print("Server hostname:", ssl_socket.server_hostname)
print("Version of the SSL Protocol:", ssl_socket.version())
print("Cipher used:", ssl_socket.cipher())
```

Finally, the ***real underlying*** problem was the version of `aiohttp==3.7.0` that we were using in our application. In the [CHANGELOG for version 3.7.1](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#371-2020-10-25), the following line shows the problem we were having:

***Fix a variable-shadowing bug causing ThreadedResolver.resolve to return the resolved IP as the hostname in each record, which prevented validation of HTTPS connections. [#5110](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/5110)***

The script I ran to test the broken versions of `aiohttp` was the following:

```py
import asyncio

import aiohttp

SERVER = "myhost.example.com"


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
        async with session.get(f"https://{SERVER}") as r:
            body = await r.json()
            print(body)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```